# FullCalendar delete event with button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, fullcalendar

I would like to start off my question with establishing exactly what I am using.
I am using a jquery calendar app devlopped by Adam Shaw called FullCalendar. 
Link: [arshaw.com/fullcalendar/](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

I want to be able to add a delete feature, so that I can delete events by clicking a delete button inside each event, and send an ajax POST to tell a mysql database to DELETE where id equals the id of the event I just deleted. However, looking through the doccumentation, I have been unable to find a way to delete an event, yet alone anything to do with that and mysql databases. If anyone would be able to help that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks, in advance.

This is my code:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    var height = "innerHeight" in window 
               ? window.innerHeight
               : document.documentElement.offsetHeight; 

    var newHeight = parseInt(height)-112;   

    $(document).ready(function() {



        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

            allDay : false,
            slotMinutes: <?php echo $tee_inc; ?>,
            minTime: "<?php echo $tee_open; ?>",
            maxTime: "<?php echo $tee_close; ?>",
            height: newHeight,
            disableDragging: true,
            disableResizing: true,          
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            editable: true,
            events: [
                <?php
                    $i=-1;
                    foreach( $tee_time_start as $tts )  {
                        $i++;
                        echo '{'; echo "\n";
                        echo "id : '".$tee_time_id[$i]."',"; echo "\n";
                        echo "title : '".$tee_first_name[$i]." ".$tee_last_name[$i]." -- ".$tee_holes[$i]." Holes -- ".$tee_phone_number[$i]." ----- <a href=\"#\" id=\"delete_time_".$tee_time_id[$i]."\">Delete</a> ',"; echo "\n";
                        echo "start : '".$tee_time_start[$i]."',"; echo "\n";
                        echo "end : '".$tee_time_end[$i]."',"; echo "\n";   
                        echo 'allDay : false'; echo "\n"; 
                        echo '},'; echo "\n";
                    }

                ?>
            ],
            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                    '(should probably update your database"+delta+")');
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            },



        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `eventClick` function. On click grab the event id and probably show a dialog box and provide delete button.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            id= calEvent.id;

            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                  resizable: false,
                  height:100,
                  width:500,
                  modal: true,
                  title: 'Want you want to do?',
                  buttons: {
                             CLOSE: function() {
                                 $("#dialog").dialog( "close" );
                             },
                             "DELETE": function() {
                                //do the ajax request?
                             }
                           }
             });
       },
```

Than in the `<body>` tag write this for dialog

```
<div id="dialog" title="" style="display:none;">Are you sure want to delete it?</div>
```

[EXAMPLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/59RCB/)

Comment: It isn't doing anything. I'm assuming (by this code) that when I click the event, a dialog box should open (at least [becuase I haven't done the ajax request yet]) when I click. However, it is not.

Comment: You need to add the html code for dialog in the body section of the page. See my updated answer

Comment: Still no dice. I click the event and nothing happens, almost seems as if it is not triggering.

Comment: I coppied it line for line, ensuring there is no misplaced code and no errors. I did a manual diagnostics to see where the problem is. The event.click function is being triggered and works because I setup a test div with an id of "test" and just put a $("#test").hide("slow"); and it hid that #test div when I clicked an event...So i'm thinking the problem is in the dialog scripting.

Comment: You have to include `jquery ui` library in order to make dialog work. See the example link in the answer.

Comment: It works. Thankyou!! now all I have to do is find out how to delete in on the front end (after the AJAX command runs) so that it will delete of the calendar without having to refresh the page. But that's a whole different story. Thankyou again.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the version of jquery used is old, I do not it out the result, so i download the updated version of jquery and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you set unique IDs to your events, you can do this to delete them individually:

`Link:`[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mastersuv/dmrkh35t)